# How do we deal with spammers

Tags: discussion

[jakuret](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/82858/jakuret) has so far answered three questions and recommended the same product.  I only woke up on the third and marked it as spam.  But they are going to continue.

While I realise that you can have any avatar/image on your account.  The photo applied at the moment is for deception.  A quick reverse search reveals that it is a [model or similar](https://yandex.com/images/search?cbir_page=similar&pos=2&url=https%3A%2F%2Favatars.mds.yandex.net%2Fget-images-cbir%2F2202473%2FBaCO1-lcEQsJVX9QS9nP7g713%2Forig&cbir_id=2202473%2FBaCO1-lcEQsJVX9QS9nP7g713&img_url=http%3A%2F%2Favatanplus.com%2Ffiles%2Fphotos%2Foriginal%2F5a33c3d60822b1605a34fc11.jpg&source=collections&rpt=imageview).

A sample image
[image]

Comment: Looks like the user got deleted, but what that picture have to do with it?

Comment: You have reposted their spam here, without obfuscating their product text.  Therefore you are a spammer.

Answer (score 4):

Flagging spam posts is the ideal way to deal with spam.

As all can verify, that spam account and all the associated spam no longer exist.